# Detect mysql password changes from logs

Tags: mysql5, security

How can I find out who last changed the MySQL database password for the "root" user.
I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Check MySQL logs, if you have them enabled.

Look into `/var/log/mysql` and grep for updates on mysql.user